# Change url path to a custom one

Tags: php, apache

I don't know how this technique is called, but here's the basic idea:

Say I have different sections within my site, and inside the address box of the browser, I don't want to show the "variable formula" to get inside a specific section of my site.

For instance, **instead** of this shown:

> www.mywebsite.com/**index.php?s=1&p=2**

**I want** this shown:

> www.mywebsite.com/**About/JohnKimbo/**

Is this possible?

Comment: It depends on what server you are using. If using Apache, for example, you can use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this videotutorial ([Basic URL Rewrite with Mod_Rewrite](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxXhjSqcHdg)) that explicitly shows how to do it without so deep understanding about many other concepts of Apache's config.

Also I recommend this [Introduction to Regular Expressions](http://codular.com/regex) made by Michael, for people who don't even understand or know about **Regex** coding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible :)

This technique is called 'URL rewriting'. The Apache guide should get you started: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to investigate [.htaccess rewrite rules](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/), and [regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) On an Apache server, you need to have mod_rewrite enabled then you can parse out the index.php and the other query string characters you don't want.

Comment: Actually I've found this easier to understand the regular expressions (or regex).. http://codular.com/regex